# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 in other than windows 10 boot C:\ drive..problem in installing...plz help me out

Tags: dual-boot

I have compaq 510 of 2 gb ram.I want to install ubuntu in same pc alongside windows 10 but in different drives not in c:. I shrinked the volume of d drive and took out 30 GB(so that i can install ubuntu in it) and left unallocated. i made my usb bootable to ubuntu but coming across selection part, i choosed something else option..the problem occurred.
1. the unallocated space doesnot shown in that partition table.
2. the total amount of space is shown in sbd4(means d drive) including unallocated and remaining of d drives altogether.
I am afraid if i mess up with sbd4 than i may loose my data in d drive.
Secondly, everytimes when i select the option: install ubuntu inside windows 10, the pc automatically restarts. i am in great dilemma . plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have the right idea to create another partition for the ubuntu install. You are also correct to create this partition from the Win10 side, and 30GB should give enough space for the install. But you will need to create an additional partition for the swap space that Linux has to have (usually double the RAM - 4GB). You may also have to format these partitions (NTFS,FAT32) to make them visible for the ubuntu install.
Now, when choosing your / partition, find the 30GB partition, change to a Linux filesystem (ext4), and choose the 4GB partition as a swap drive (filesystem will be swap).
If you only had a c: drive and created a 30GB d: partition, this partition should be empty unless you put data in the drive. Make sure that this partition and the swap partition are empty BEFORE starting the ubuntu install.
follow these instructions and the install should go as you wish it to including GRUB setting up the dual boot that I believe you are looking for.           Good luck Craig